# App Engine inaccessible from Google Cloud Platform Developer Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I created an App Engine Project using https://appengine.google.com

I try to access App Engine from Google Cloud Platform Developer Console but fail.

- Overview -> Take the Google App Engine quickstart (it prompt "To access App Engine, you must be a direct member of the project.")
- I click on left menu Compute -> App Engine (nothing happened)
- I check Permissions (my account is the Owner)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you first went to the old console (https://appengine.google.com), create an application, then try to access it from the new console (https://console.developers.google.com).

You can fix it by staying in the old console, clicking on the app id, then going to Administration -> Application Settings, then scrolling to the bottom and clicking on the button under 'Cloud Integration'.

Comment: There in nothing to click at "Cloud Integration". It says "The project was created successfully" since this project is created. The problem occur when I do Application Settings -> Domain Setup -> Setup Google App + App Engine Integration, then the Cloud Platform Console -> App Engine stop working.

Comment: If this is the case then you may need to create a new project from https://console.developers.google.com. Its not a good idea to create new projects from the old console as you can run into this problem.